# Как удалить элемент списка по клику на привязанную кнопку?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть список с кнопками. И каждая кнопка объединена с отдельным элементом списка.

```
<ul>
    <li>1<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li>2<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li>3<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```

С помощью Javascript мне нужно удалить тот элемент списка, на какую кнопку я нажму. То есть, если я нажимаю на кнопку, привязанную к первому элементу, этот первый элемент должен быть удалён.

Answer (score 3):

```js
document.querySelector('ul').onclick = function(e) {
  const btn = e.target.closest('.delete');
  if (!btn) {
    return;
  }
  
  btn.parentElement.remove();
  // btn.closest('li').remove();
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>1<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li>2<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
    <li>3<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>
</ul>
```